# Create powershell cmdlet that processes each path received from dir

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a cmdlet written in powershell that can accept each path from dir command and run a powershell function on this path.  Example:

```
PS> dir *.ext | Convert-xyz
```

Here's what I tried below. Except, it only processes the first item listed by dir *.ext and then exits.

```
function Convert-xyz {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string[]]$path,

        [string[]]$function
    )

    foreach ($pathi in $path) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor "Yellow" "`nPath: $pathi"
        foreach ($funct in $function) {
            write-host -ForegroundColor "Green" "Function: $funct"
            switch($funct) {
                "reflow"   {reflow  ($pathi);  break}
                "desquare" {desquare($pathi);  break}

                default   {
                    write-host -ForegroundColor "Red" "Unknown function: $funct"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Write-Host "End"

} #function
```

Comment: You'll need a `foreach` in there, something like `dir *.exe | %{convert-xyz}`

Comment: Aside: Your function calls are not correct semantically. PowerShell functions are not called with `( )`. The calls should beshould be `reflow $pathi` and `desquare $pathi`, not `reflow ($pathi)` and `desquare ($pathi)`.

Answer (score 1):

For handling pipeline input you'll want to put your processing code in a `Process {}` block.

```
function Convert-xyz {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$path,

        [string[]]$function
    )

    Process {
        foreach ($pathi in $path) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor "Yellow" "`nPath: $pathi"
            foreach ($funct in $function) {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor "Green" "Function: $funct"
                switch ($funct) {
                    "reflow"   {reflow   $pathi; break}
                    "desquare" {desquare $pathi; break}
                    default    {
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor "Red" "Unknown function: $funct"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        Write-Host "End"
    }
} #function
```

The content of that block is run for every input from the pipeline (which doesn't come as an array, but one item at a time).

See also [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413265.aspx) from Don Jones.

Note that you'll *still* need to pass the function you want to invoke on the input as a parameter, though:

```
dir *.ext | Convert-xyz -Function 'reflow'
```